How to fix 'Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts' on login on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS?
When I login to my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS server (upgraded from 22 LTS) directly after the 'Welcome to Ubuntu' line I get:

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your internet connection or proxy settings.


While it is accessible:

Also other DNS and ping commands work fine.
